# Getting the address of list[0].next in Sigma16 and calling it X1

Tags: list, memory, memory-address

I have a question where I need to find the address of list[0].next and call it X1. But I am not sure how to do this. I am using Sigma16 for this. Can someone help me ?

I have looked at the memory but I don't understand what exactly I am looking at.